# Is there a way to call on specific number in a range when using a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I'm pretty new so sorry if this is a dumb question.

I watching some python learning videos and was trying to do some different things using the same concepts. In the video, they demonstrated making a grid using user inputed symbols like this:

```
rows = int(input("How many rows? "))
columns = int(input("How many columns? "))
symbols = input("Please put in a symbol: ")

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        print(symbol, end="")
    print()
```

From this, I was thinking, "Hey can I make python draw a box using user inputed number of rows and columns?"

I tried making this code:

```
columns = int(input("How many columns? "))

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns)[0]:
        print("|", end="")
    for j in range(columns):
        print("_", end="")
    for j in range(columns)[-1]:
        print("|", end="")
    print()
```

This didn't run because it says int object is not iterable; however, I'm not sure why? Ranges are able to be used in for loops, but is it not possible to call on a specific value in the range to perform the for loop?

My reasoning for my code is that whenever a number in the range of the column is 0, then I want it to print "|" to make the sides of the box.

Comment: You don't want a `for` loop for the left and right edge.  Just do the print, then do `range(columns-2)` for the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because you're trying to do a for loop over an integer rather than something iterable like a list. `range(columns)[0]` returns the first element in that range, which is the integer `0`, so your line of code:

```
for j in range(columns)[0]:
```

is really saying:

```
for j in 0:
```

which python won't like.

To get what you're looking for using a structure similar to the one you shared, you can try this:

```
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        if i == 0 or i == rows-1:
            print("_", end="")
        elif j == 0 or j == columns-1:
            print("|", end="")
        else:
            print(" ", end="")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call range, it essentially creates a list (not quite, but I think of it that way) that the for loop iterates through. When you index `range(columns)` you get an integer. You can't iterate through an integer. If you want your first and last column to be a `|`, try this code.

```
for i in range(rows):
    print("|", end="")
    for j in range(columns - 2):
        print("_", end="")
    print("|")
```